# Whats the use of this input box?

Tags: php, html, facebook, forms

```
<input type="hidden" value="€,´,€,´,水,Д,Є" name="charset_test">

<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="Zo_ap" name="lsd" id="lsd">
```

i saw this in facebook login page.what the use of this?? and also i need to know wats the use of autocomplete ="off" in hidden input box..

Comment: looks like it contains one chinese character in it.

Comment: This is not an input box. It's a hidden value. I assume it is there for form-posting so the receiving page knows what sort of charset is (capable of) being used

Comment: Hmm, clever way of testing charset.

Answer (score 2):

charset_test prints out UNICODE characters to the DOM of the browser, and then javascript checks to see if the browser can render it correctly. This is for localization, to provide localized resource strings to users in other regions.

Autocomplete is for search, if you don't konw what Autocomplete is, I would google it :)

Answer (score 1):

The hidden INPUT tag allows HTML form developers to store information for delivery with the form data that is invisible to the form users. The hidden form fields are used to save state in multi-page forms, collect cookie data to deliver to the form, and just store data beyond what the customer fills in.

Comment: although your answer is technically correct, it doesn't answer the question of shanmugavel-php. Please try and address the question more directly.

Answer (score 0):

> Autocomplete is for search, if you don't konw what Autocomplete is, I would google it :)

Kudos on the explanation of the charset_test, but I don't really agree with the autocomplete statement. Although an autocompleted input element through javascript is a rather common phenomenon, this is not for a Javascript, this is for Internet Explorer. Internet Explorer "remembers" what you have typed (so do the others, btw), and tagging an input with 'autocomplete="off"' means that you're telling internet explorer *not* to display a list with recently typed information when the user clicks in it. [This behaviour is documented by Microsoft.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Still strange that they use it on a hidden field though. Hidden fields are not supposed to receive any user input.